# combineLatest does not exist on type using Angular 11 and RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

Good Evening,
I am trying to use the combineLatest operator to combine two streams in Angular, but I am getting the error "combineLatest does not exist on type".
I have tried to take the code and put it into a .pipe(), but that does not work.
Do I need to pipe map and then combineLatest?
Thanks for your help!

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject, BehaviorSubject, Observable, combineLatest} from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Model and Service imports
import {Thread} from './thread.model';
import {Message} from '../message/message.model';
import {MessagesService} from '../message/messages.service';

import * as _ from 'lodash';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ThreadsService {
threads: Observable<{[key:string]: Thread}>; // (a)
orderedThreads: Observable<Thread[]>; // (a1)
currentThread: Subject<Thread> = new BehaviorSubject<Thread>(new Thread()); // (a2)
currentThreadMessages: Observable<Message[]>; // (a3)

  constructor(public messagesService: MessagesService) { 
    
    this.threads = messagesService.messages // (b)
      .pipe( map((messages: Message[]) => {
        const threads: { [key: string]: Thread } = {}; //(b1)

        messages.map((message: Message) => { // (b2)
          this.threads[message.thread.id] =
            this.threads[message.thread.id] ||
            message.thread;

          const messagesThread: Thread = // (c)
            threads[message.thread.id];
          if (!messagesThread.lastMessage || messagesThread.lastMessage.sentAt < message.sentAt) {
            messagesThread.lastMessage = message;
          }
        });
        return threads;
      }))
      
    this.orderedThreads = this.threads // (d)
      .pipe(map((threadGroups: { [key: string]: Thread }) => {
        const threads: Thread[] = _.values(threadGroups);
        return _.sortBy(threads, (t: Thread) => t.lastMessage.sentAt).reverse();
      }));  

      this.currentThread.subscribe(this.messagesService.markThreadAsRead); // (e1)

    this.currentThreadMessages = combineLatest([this.currentThread, messagesService.messages]).pipe(
      map(currentThread: Thread, messages: Message[]) => {
        if(currentThread && messages.length > 0) {
      return _.chain(messages)
        .filter((message: Message) => // (f1)
          (message.thread.id === currentThread.id))
        .map((message: Message) => {
          message.isRead = true;
          return message;
        })
        .value();
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
);
    }

  setCurrentThread(newThread: Thread): void { // (e)
    this.currentThread.next(newThread);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `.combineLatest` on an `Observable`. The syntax for using combine latest is

```
newObservable$ = combineLatest([observable1$, observable2$, ...]).pipe(...)
```

In your case you can have

```
 this.currentThreadMessages = combineLatest([this.currentThread, messagesService.messages]).pipe(
  map(currentThread: Thread, messages: Message[]) => {
     if (currentThread && messages.length > 0) {
          return _.chain(messages)
              .filter((message: Message) => // (f1)
                (message.thread.id === currentThread.id))
              .map((message: Message) => {
                message.isRead = true;
                return message;
              })
              .value();
        } else {
            return [];
        }
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I put this into my project and it returns many more errors. For the currentThread and messages it says that it cant find the name and in the return at the bottom it says 'unreachable code detected'. I will edit what I have above to include your snippet